# How to display an alert Indicator after being redirected?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flask

I have a page that redirects users after clicking a submit button successfully to the homepage.

I want to display an indicator like this:

[image]

under the navigation bar of the homepage after being redirected back to it from the submit button.

How can I do that? excuse me I'm new to web development.

Comment: in ASP.NET MVC you can use TempData

Comment: im using flassk

Comment: How do you do the redirection? Are you using any JS framework?

Comment: No , just html,  basic js and flask in python and some databases from sqlite
in flask i can do the redirection like this: return redirect("/home")

Comment: In that case, you are reloading the web page so the state on the client side is lost. I would suggest you to use `sessionStorage` on the client side. Prepare a value before the possible redirect and then, read it from the target page (and clean it after).

Comment: sessionStorage seems like a possible solution. Although, I think there is a better way of quickly getting your info across. Would you be able to share your code? I will point out the solution then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flask supports flashed messages. https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/flashing/

In my opinion, this is better than using a cookie to display temporary popups.

So to set a flashed message, you do the following:

```
@app.route('/sample')
def sample():
    if successCheck()
        flash('You were successfully logged in')
    return redirect("/index")
```

And in the template, to retrieve the flashed message, you do this:

```
{% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
  {% if messages %}
    <ul class=flashes>
    {% for message in messages %}
      <li>{{ message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endif %}
{% endwith %}
```

You can also use categories:

```
# Route
flash(u'Invalid password provided', 'error')
```

```
# Template
{% with messages = get_flashed_messages(with_categories=true) %}
  {% if messages %}
    <ul class=flashes>
    {% for category, message in messages %}
      <li class="{{ category }}">{{ message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endif %}
{% endwith %}
```

Or this template option:

```
# Template
{% with errors = get_flashed_messages(category_filter=["error"]) %}
{% if errors %}
<div class="alert-message block-message error">
  <a class="close" href="#">×</a>
  <ul>
    {%- for msg in errors %}
    <li>{{ msg }}</li>
    {% endfor -%}
  </ul>
</div>
{% endif %}
{% endwith %}
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can create a response in flask that redirects and also sets a cookie. Something like

```
from flask import make_response

response = make_response(redirect('/homepage'))
response.set_cookie('show_success_flash', 'true')

return response
```

Then, on your JS side you can read the cookie, and if it's true, show the message. Then, you can either remove the cookie when dismissing the flash message or remove it after a setTimeout. Something like:

```
// homepage.js


const cookie = import 'js-cookie'

if (cookie.get('show_success_flash') {
  const successFlash = document.getElementById('success_flash_message')

  if (successFlash.style.display === 'none') {
    successFlash.style.display = 'block'
  }
}
```

Comment: is true in response.set_cookie('show_success_flash', true) a variable? cause when i try something like this it says true is not defined

Comment: @Yoda My mistake, it looks like that method accepts a string: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Response.set_cookie. I'm rusty on my  python. I'll update my answer